# Error compiling with polyc on Debian 10 Buster

Tags: polyml

"/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpolyml"

I received this error when compiling a source sml file with polyc on Debian 10.

Answer (score 2):

polyc requires the deb package 'libpolyml-dev', even though it is not installed by default when installing the deb package 'polyml'.
So, 'apt install libpolyml-dev' resolved the issue.